# Flutter Firebase: 2 different ways of fetching user photourl

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-authentication

```
content: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      _buildUserPic1(),
      _buildUserPic2()
    ],
  ),
```

The following are the two ways in which I am trying to fetch the photo of a user signed in using Google Firebase Auth.

```
Container _buildUserPic(){
    return Container(
      child: Image.network(
        user.photoUrl
      ),
    );
  }
```

and the second way is

```
Container _buildUserPic2(){
return Container(
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage(widget.url), 
    )
  ),
  )
);}
```

The first one successfully produces the profile picture but the other gives an error. What is the correct way to get the image? Should I use asynchronous methods to obtain the image?

Edit:
`user` is an instance of `FirebaseUser`.

`widget.url` is for accessing the `String url` (in a Stateful widget) where

```
final String url = user.photoUrl;
```

Edit2:

```
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn gsa = new GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await gsa.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await firebaseauth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    );

    user = firebaseUser;
    googleSignIn = gsa;
    }
```

Comment: what is the user and widget variables?

Comment: where do you get the 'user' ? do you pass the user as parameter in your widget?  could you print "widget.url" in your _buildUserPic2 method? what error do you get in the console ?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: the error I am getting is that photoUrl is null

Comment: which is null  : widget.url or  user.photoUrl? how do you pass 'user' into your widget?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, `widget.url` can call `String url` from a `StatefulWidget`.

If `_signIn()` was called after the screen was built, `user` will be `null` on `String url`. Given that `final` was also set on `String url`, its value can't be changed.

What I suggest that you can do here is to maintain a repository of user data using [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package and update its data depending on the user that's currently logged-in. You can read this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for more details.